# Where to insert the definition of a function in mathematica:

Tags: function-construction

The whole procedure is much more complicated but the heart of the problem is the following. The variables are `h` and `x`. I define the function `m` containing h,x and the derivative of another function `p`:

```
m[h_, x_] := u[h, x, D[p[h, x], x]] + x
```

I need the derivatives of `m`:

```
mh[h_, x_] := D[m[h, x], h]; 
mx[h_, x_] := D[m[h, x], x];
```

From the derivatives of `m` I solve for the second derivatives of `p`:

```
solution = Solve[{mh[h, x] == 0, mx[h, x] == 0}, {D[p[h, x], h, x], D[p[h, x], x, x]}]; 
phx[h_, x_] := solution[[1]][[1, 2]] 
pxx[h_, x_] := solution[[1]][[2, 2]]
```

Finally I need the expression:

```
expression[h_, x_] := phx[h, x] pxx[h, x]
```

AT THIS POINT I write explicitly the dependence of `u` in terms of `h`, `x` and the derivative of p:

```
u[h, x, D[p[h, x], x]] = h D[p[h, x], x]^2;
```

`mh[h,x]` gives the expected result:

```
mh[h, x] p^(0,1)(h,x)^2+2 h p^(1,1)(h,x) p^(0,1)(h,x)
```

However, the `expression[h, x]` gives me an unexpected result:

```
 -(((-u^(0,1,0)(h,x,p^(0,1)(h,x))-1) u^(1,0,0)(h,x,p^(0,1)(h,x)))/u^(0,0,1)(h,x,p^(0,1)(h,x))^2)
```

I do not see the reason. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

m[h_, x_] := u[h, x, D[p[h, x], x]] + x
mh[h_, x_] := D[m[h, x], h];
mx[h_, x_] := D[m[h, x], x];

solution = 
  Solve[{mh[h, x] == 0, mx[h, x] == 0}, {D[p[h, x], h, x], 
    D[p[h, x], x, x]}];

phx[h_, x_] := solution[[1]][[1, 2]]
pxx[h_, x_] := solution[[1]][[2, 2]]

expression[h_, x_] := phx[h, x] pxx[h, x]
```

**Replace `u` with a pure function**

```
repl = u -> (#1*#3^2 &);

mh[h, x] /. repl

(* Derivative[0, 1][p][h, x]^2 + 
   2*h*Derivative[0, 1][p][h, x]*Derivative[1, 1][p][h, x] *)

expression[h, x] /. repl

(* 1/(4 h^2) *)
```